# Print custom formatted text into cmd console

Tags: python, colors, console, colorama

I just started learning python in order to do some stuff for the company I work for. I want to add a command line option like -doc but Ì somehow struggle with adding color or any other custom text format to my documentation (to be printed in cmd).

I have following problems:

**1. Ansi escaping doesn't work as I expect when reading tutorials on the internet:**

This code: `print('\033[31m' + 'Hello' + '\033[0m')` doesn't escape at all so I end up with this output: `[31mHello[0m`

**2. I can't import colorama because my users have a plain python installation and I can't just add libraries to it. So my plan would be to add colorama to my project structure.**

**To 1**: Do I misunderstand something important or has someone an idea what I`m doing wrong?

**To 2**: Is there a way to install colarama into my project without any changes to the plain python installation or dependencies to the outside of my project?

... I would accept any other solution to my problem.

Comment: And what is your platform and terminal type? If you are on Windows, generally speaking, you have to use Windows API calls (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors/3332860#comment3901803_3332860)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print in terminal with colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors)

Comment: OK, looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors is a comprehensive guide on color terminal printing in Python, including Windows cmd without Colorama (https://stackoverflow.com/a/288556/11255447)

Comment: My target environment is standard cmd from windows. Wait ill go through your links, maybe it is helping me already.

Comment: Ok, I know some of the pages you send me. For some reason I cant get my Console not to print out the explizit ansi code. Other guides are refering to non-windows consoles so ill ignore them. I feel like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors/3332860#comment3901803_3332860 ist the right answer to my question. I need to find out how to use windows calls. Ill write a solution as soon as i found out. Thanks for your help so far,

Answer (score 0):

Just use batch to do that.

Code:
@echo ^[[31mHello^[[0m
(^ is ctrl)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).